# How can I clean my peeler?

Tags: equipment

I have a peeler that I've been using for a while. It's gotten quite rusty and dirty. Of course, I can toss it at this point and start with a new peeler... But is there any way to clean it? Anything I can soak it in that would remove the rust?

Comment: what kind of peeler is it?

Comment: With your next peeler, rinse it and dry it after every use and it will last a very long time.

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22107/how-can-i-sharpen-my-peeler

Comment: @nice - thanks. I rinse it, but I imagine it's the drying part that's the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soak in a mild borax solution. fill the sink and throw in gummed up juicers, colanders and tea-stained spoons as well.

If your kitchen is humid, a bit of an oil rub after thorough drying should slow down the rust.